# How to use stream instead of for loop

Tags: java, java-stream

I would like to write the code below using Stream, instead of with a for loop

```
private Car getCar(String CarRef, List<Car> cars) {
    for (Car car : cars) {
        if (carRef.equals(car.getName())) {
            return car;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: See the Javadoc of [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html)—you have a filter operation and a "find first" operation. Would probably also be a good idea to read the [package Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) of `java.util.stream`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*findFirst()* return an optional, so the exact solution is:

```
return cars.stream() 
         .filter(car -> carRef.equals(car.getName())) // keep only matching elements
         .findFirst() // when 1st element matches, it triggers return
         .orElse(null);   // If not element, return null
```

Comment: Thank you. This format is supported on Java 9+ though, and Im working on Java 8 codebase. I think that in my case I need to type it like this in the end:

return cars.stream() 
         .filter(car -> carRef.equals(car.getName())) // keep only matching elements
         .findFirst() // when 1st element matches, it triggers return
         .orElse(null);   // If not element, return null

Comment: indeed, I fixed the answer

Answer (score 1):

Your solution should be:

```
cars.stream()
    .filter(c -> carRef.equals(c.getName()))
    .findFirst();
```

- take the steam from a collection.
- filter with condition which you need (you could create boolean method and use it for filtering).
- get the first value which matches with this condition.

If you want ***all cars*** which matches to the condition, use:

```
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Instead of `findFirst()`.

Mostly much better idea will be return `Optional<Car>` from the method than unwrap it there.

Comment: you have a typo streem()

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful